# how to find sum of integer in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's suppose I have an integer value as

`const num = 123456789`

and I want to print the sum of these no. in react as 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 = 45

`expect output = 45`

approach I am following is as follows

```
const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);

const num = 123456789
for (const element of num ) {
   setTotal(total + element) 
}

console.log(total)
```

Output I am getting is : `01`

Need your help here please!

Comment: You don't need state for this task `\`${n}\`.split('').map(Number).reduce((a,b) => a+b, 0)`

Comment: Did you debug what element is in your for loop?

Answer (score 4):

You can continuously divide by 10 until the number becomes 0 and use `% 10` to get the last digit.

```js
let num = 123456789;
let sum = 0;
for (; num; num = Math.floor(num / 10)) 
  sum += num % 10;
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner

```js
const num = 123456789
console.log(num.toString().split('').reduce((acc, elem) => elem*1+acc, 0))
```